# How to connect to EKS cluster from cloud 9 instance using kubectl

Tags: amazon-eks, aws-cloud9

I have created cluster through AWS console and trying to connect to it from cloud9 using kubectl but I am seeing following error
error: You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized)
Details

1. -I created cluster by logging in as root user
2. -I turnded off temporary credentials in cloud9 settings
3. -I configured my root use credentials in cloud9 instance and created profile for the same
4. -I used following command to set
   aws eks update-kubeconfig --name my-cluster --region us-east-1 --role-arn arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXX:role/eksadmin-role --profile user1
   Unfortunately I am unable to connect to the cluster can someone please help me in understanding where exactly the issue is

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eksctl` to update the kubeconfig like below,

```
eksctl utils write-kubeconfig --cluster <cluster-name> --authenticator-role-arn <role arn to create the eks cluster>
```

Also you can directly edit the configmap `aws-auth` in namespace `kube-system` to grant the permission to other IAM users/roles to access your cluster. See doc https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/add-user-role.html for detail.